# Avoidland - min number of steps to place n pawns so that there is only in each row and column?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Avoidland is a puzzle played on an n×n board with n pawns. The pawns are initially placed on the squares of the board, at most one pawn per square. The goal is to move the pawns so that they “avoid” each other—there cannot be a row or a column with more than one pawn. In one move a pawn can move to a neighboring unoccupied square, that is, a square that shares a side with the pawn’s current location and there is no pawn on it. Given the initial locations of the pawns, what is the minimum number of moves needed to solve the puzzle?

Input
The first line contains an integer n, then n lines follow. The i-th line contains the initial row and column coordinates of the i-th pawn, separated by space. Each coordinate is an integer between 1 and n. You may assume that n is at most 1000000.

Output
The line contains the minimum number of moves needed to solve the puzzle.

```
Sample Input 1   
3
1 3
2 3
3 1

Sample Output 1
1


Sample Input 2  
4
1 4
4 1
1 1
4 4

Sample Output 2
4
```

My approach:
The solution would require each row and column to have 1 pawn exactly.
For the initial configuration, make a rightmost column which contains the sum of the number of pawns in each row.
Make a bottom row which contains the sum of the number of pawns in each column. 
Now we need to find the minimum number of steps to make each of these arrays into all 1s and add them up but I am confused how to do that.

Comment: People do not write code from scratch here. What have *you* written so far?

Comment: This question might fit http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ better.

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach is a great one.  Once you have computed the histogram of pawns in each row/column, you can use a greedy algorithm to count the moves.

Suppose we have a 0,0,3,1 histogram that we need to change into 1,1,1,1.

It is clear that we may as well move the pawn closest to the left into the first position, the second pawn closest to the left into the second position, etc.

Therefore simply iterate through the histogram and add up the distance between the i^th pawn found and position i (where we want to place it).

e.g. in Python:

```
A = [0,0,3,1]

t = 0
i = 0
for pos,count in enumerate(A):
    for k in range(count):
        t += abs(pos-i)
        i += 1
print t
```

This prints an answer of 3, corresponding to moving one pawn left twice, and one pawn left once.

The complexity is O(n) because the inner loop is executed exactly once for each pawn.

Comment: (Addressing deleted comment about the pawns colliding when they are moved) Can you provide a counter example?  My code is simply counting the moves. I agree that in some cases you may need to move pawns in a different order, but  I claim that there will always be a way of moving the pawns to achieve the flat histogram by only ever moving pawns into empty bins.  Suppose you had to move a pawn on top of another one, then simply move the other one first.  The only way it goes wrong is if the two pawns need to move in opposite directions, but this will never happen in an optimal solution.

Comment: Never mind. I was wrong and I think your method is correct. But that should be proved that this will give min moves. I am not sure about that. ...but now I am looking on picture and realize that there can't be solutions in less moves. So your solution I think is absolutely correct.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Isn't the problem two dimensional? For example, what if your example, `[0,0,3,1]`, represented the row histogram of the following (x,y) points on a board numbered 1 to 4: `{(4,1),(4,2),(3,2),(2,2)}` ?

Comment: @גלעדברקן You are right, the problem is 2D, but the questioner explained how to convert it into 2 1D problems.  The idea is that you need to add the steps to make the row histogram flat to the steps needed to make the column histogram flat.  Your example has histograms os [0,0,3,1] and [2,1,1,0] so you need 3 steps for the rows and 3 steps for the columns, so the total is 6 for the 2d problem.

Answer (score 0):

The guess with histogram is cool. That is the starting point. Let's note that changing for instance horizontal histogram doen't have effect on vertical histogram and the opposite is also true. So you should apply your algorithm twice on vertical and horizontal histogram, but algorithms are the same. So I will consider only horizontal one.

Now suppose we have the following `{U(0), U(1), ..., U(n-2), O(n-1)}` here `O(k)` represents occupied and `U(k)` unoccupied square on `k`-th position. Now it is obvious that moving a pawn from `j` position to `i` position when all squares are unoccupied is just the diffrence of their positions `j-i`. Now we will show that it is also true for general case when we have some occupied squares. Suppose we have the following histogram:

```
{..U(i),..O(k1),..,O(k2),..,O(kl),..,O(j),...}
```

I.e. we want to move `O(j)` to `U(i)` but we also have `l` squares occupied. Lets first move `O(k1)` to `U(i)`: that is done in `k1-i` steps. Now we move `O(k2)` to `U(k1)`: `k2-k1` steps.....And in the end move `O(j)` to `U(kl)`: `j-kl` steps. What we have:

```
(k1-i)+(k2-k1)+(k3-k2)+....+(kl-k(l-1))+(j-kl) => j-i
```

So we proved that moving a pawn from one position to nother is just the diffrence in positions.

Now the implementation in `C#`. We will do 2 parallel walk through the histogram. To understand it lets consider example:

```
0   0   0   3   2
```

`i` will search for empty position, `j` will search for position where `count > 1`.

```
int i = 0, j = 0, c = 0;

while(i < n && j < n)
{
    while(h[i] <> 0) i++;
    while(h[j] < 2) j++;

    c += Math.Abs(j - i++);
    h[j] = h[j] - 1;
}

Firt step:  i == 0, j == 3, c == 3, h[3] == 2
Second:     i == 1, j == 3, c == 5, h[3] == 1
Third:      i == 2, j == 4, c == 7, h[4] == 1
```

Complexity of this algorithm  is `O(2n)`. We have 2 histograms so whole complexity is `O(4n) = O(n)`.